# Automatically elevate Windows setup to admin mode

Tags: windows, installation, setup-project

We have legacy desktop native app with custom setup. The setup is signed and must be run as administrator. Current prod setup EXE that was built and signed 5 years ago is automatically elevated and run as admin on Windows 7 or 8. The setup we rebuilt now and is also signed with different cert and has the same name as old one is not automatically elevated to admin and therefore fails.

What makes Windows to run the setup EXE automatically as admin?

Comment: Most likely: the old setup has no manifest, but Windows is successfully guessing that it is a setup program and requesting elevation.  The new setup has a manifest, but you haven't explicitly configured requestedExecutionLevel so it is set to the default value, asInvoker.  If you're using Microsoft build tools, check the value of the /MANIFESTUAC linker option.  You want to set it to requireAdministrator.

Answer (score 0):

Signing is not related to admin privileges, so don't worry about it in that respect.

To expand on Harry Johnson's comment (which is correct), early versions of UAC on Windows used to automatically elevate programs that looked like setup programs. I don't know the exact algorithm used, but programs with setup or install in the names or descriptions were elevated. That doesn't happen any more, and on UAC programs run by admins are not elevated unless they explicitly elevate with a manifest or a run as administrator.

Without knowing where that setup.exe comes from, if you build it. or it comes with a version of a setup tool (Visual Studio?) then it's hard to say how to fix it.

If this happens to be an MSI-based install then the MSI will ask for elevation if it's marked that way. It's not clear from the question which part of the setup requires elevation, but if it's setup.exe that actually does the install, then all of it needs elevation and it needs an elevation manifest.

Comment: The behaviour of UAC hasn't changed, but the heuristics only apply to applications with no manifest - it's a backwards compatibility measure.  What has changed is that modern build tools always include a manifest.